# Computer Management: error message - cannot assign letter to drive

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to assign letter to drive getting error message from Disk management "the operation failed to complete because the disk management console view is not up-to-date. Refresh the view by using the refresh task.  If the problem persists close the Disk Management console, then restart Disk Management or restart the computer.

Restarted computer dose not help.

Comment: Is it a USB device you are trying to assign a letter to?...http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/disk-management-console-view-is-not-up-to-date/42b1ebc3-edaf-4c3f-93cd-beda4bab2671

Comment: +1 for that comment, should also work on non-USB drives.

Comment: Its not connected through a USB slot, its connected through sata. it dose not show up there. i have 2 partition on that drive, other partition works fine

Comment: Something about that partition that windows does not like, what kind of partition is it?

Answer (score 2):

Open device manager (not disk manager)
Look for any "unknown disk" (and any other unknowns at this point would probably be good to fix)
Right click and uninstall
scan for hardware changes

As a last resort:
Start an admin command prompt
diskpart
list disk
sel disk # (whatever your disk id is)
uniqueid disk (note the number)
sel part # (whatever partition you want to mount)
detail part (note the offset in bytes)

Open calc
Switch to "programmer mode"
Enter the offset in bytes, noted above
choose "hex". Note the hex value of the offset

Open regedit
Navigate to HKLM\System\MountedDevices
You will see a list of Volume{GUID} and \DosDevices\:
Each of them will have data which is the concatenation of disk id and partition offset

First, look for the existing disk signature in the data of volume and dosdevices. The order is LSB, so you will need to "backwards read". For example, if your disk id is 677a2344, it will appear as 44 23 7a 67.

If you find any disk ID matches for the disk, delete them (may want to back up first in case?) and reboot. Don't forget to write down the ID and offset! After reboot, check to see if there's a drive letter, if not, continue.

Post reboot, or if you don't see the disk ID anywhere, we're going to try creating our own dosdevices entry. To do this, right click "MountedDevices" and choose "new>binary value". Type \DosDevices\X: (or whatever letter you want that is currently unused). For the data, enter the disk ID in LSB order, followed by the partition offset in LSB order, padded to 8 bytes (e.g. if the hex offset you saw was 100000, the 8 byte LSB version of that would be 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00)

Exit regedit and reboot. Hopefully that works...